# Yii2: Populating model field with value from many-to-many relation

Tags: rest, yii2, many-to-many

We are trying to set-up our REST API in a way that a user can only retrieve data related to his account. Uptill now, We've only had a public API and it all worked like a charm.
The public API will still get used, so we started from scratch.

We have a `User` model, extending `ActiveRecord` and implementing `IdentityInterface`. A User will have a relation to a `Customer` model (Many:Many, but at least one). A User will have `only one MASTER` Customer. 
The above is saved in the database using 3 tables `app_customer_users`,`app_customers` and `link_customer_users_customers`. The join table contains a boolean field `master`.

In the User model:

```
public function getCustomers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Customer::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id'])
        ->viaTable('link_customer_users_customers', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

In the Customer model:

```
public function getUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
        ->viaTable('link_customer_users_customers', ['customer_id' => 'id']);
}
```

This works great if we would request all customers, they'll have 'users' populated (if we add it in `extraFields` etc, etc...)

The new API uses `Basic user:pass` in authentication, and we can get the current user object/identity by calling `Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()`.

### NOW THE PROBLEM

We would like to be able to include the Customer ID when a user connects in a way that we can get it by calling `Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()->customer_id` OR `Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()->getCustomerId()` The Customer ID should be the ID where `master` in the join table `== true`.

We've tried adding it to `fields`, as we did before with `hasOne` relations, but in this case it does not seem to work:

```
$fields['customer_id'] = function($model) {
    return $model->getCustomers()->where('link_customer_users_customers.master', true)->one()->customer_id;
}; // probably the where part is our porblem?
```

And we've tried creating a custom getter like this:

```
public function getCustomerId() {
    return $this->getCustomers()->andFilterWhere(['link_customer_users_customers.master' => true])->one()->customer_id;
}
```

This last attempt resulted in an **error**:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'link_customer_users_customers.master' in 'where clause'\nThe SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `app_customers` WHERE (`link_customer_users_customers`.`master`=TRUE) AND (`id`='93')
```

We've been searching in the docs and on Google, but did not find an example on how to do this.

### SOLUTION

Based on accepted answer we added some code.

In `User` model:

```
// Include customer always with user
public static function findIdentity($id) {
    return static::findOne($id)->with('customer');
}

// Next to `getCustomers()`, added this `hasOne` relation to get only the customer from
// which the current user is the master user
public function getCustomer() {
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id'])
        ->viaTable('link_customer_users_customers', ['user_id' => 'id'], function ($query) {
            $query->andWhere(['master' => 1]);
        });
}

// Getter, just because
public function getCustomerId() {
    return $this->customer->id;
}
```

And now we can get the ID from the customer by calling `Yii::$app->user->getIdentity()->customer->id` OR `Yii::$app->user->identity->customer->id` etc, etc.. in the project..

Comment: what i am trying to understand is that a user itself can also be a customer?

Comment: A customer will have at least one master user.. the master user is the one used to connect with API. But other employees (of our customers) migt have users to. And a User can be linked to multiple Customer accounts. But one user will only be master user for one Customer account. So if the master user logs in at API, we would like to know for which Customer Account we need to select data.

Comment: can you please add the following relation `public function getMasterCustomerId() {
        return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id'])
        ->viaTable('link_customer_users_customers', ['user_id' => 'id']);
        ->andOnCondition(['=','{{%link_customer_users_customers}}.master',true]);
    }` to `User`  model and try with `Yii::$app->user->identity->masterCustomerId` , if i understood correctly the `master` field is in the `link_customer_users_customers` .

Comment: it should be `Yii::$app->user->identity->masterCustomerId->id` sorry for missing it in my previous comment

Comment: It still does not include a join with the join table. But I think I figured it out using your relation as a starting point.

Comment: your `viaTable` is already joining it with `link_customer_users_customers` you dont need any other join statement

Comment: Yes, but the `viaTable` is a separate query, the condition should be function as last parameter of `viaTable`, correct?

Comment: Yes you can move that condition inside the `viaTable` as another condition  that would be more better and right way to do I added an extra `andOnCondition()` .

Comment: if you add an answer, I will accept it. I'll update my question with complete code I added.

Comment: have you added the condition in the `viaTable` as `->viaTable('link_customer_users_customers', ['user_id' => 'id','master'=>true])` or `->viaTable('link_customer_users_customers', ['user_id' => 'id'],function($query){$query->onCondition(['master'=>true])})` ? i think the first one wont work but hte second one will .

Comment: Check my updated question :)

Comment: yes Thats  what i was talking about. you **should** use `anonymous` function here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a relation like below and use an `anonymous` function as the third parameter to the `viaTable` to add another condition to check `master` field as true.

```
public function getMasterCustomerId() {
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['id' => 'customer_id'])
    ->viaTable('link_customer_users_customers', ['user_id' => 'id'],function($query){
       $query->andWhere(['master' => 1]);
   });
}
```

and then you can use it for the logged in user as below.

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->masterCustomerId->id;
```

Comment: You are our hero-of-the-day! :)