# Yii2 rest: checkAccess on restAction

Tags: rest, yii2

After tackling [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662348/yii2-populating-model-field-with-value-from-many-to-many-relation) we would now like to check if the authenticated user can view, update or delete an existing record. Since `checkAccess()` is called by default in all `restAction`s the following seemed the most logic thing to try:

```
public function checkAccess($action, $model = null, $params = []) {
    if(in_array($action, ['view', 'update', 'delete'])) {
        if(Yii::$app->user->identity->customer->id === null
         || $model->customer_id !== Yii::$app->user->identity->customer->id) {
            throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('You can\'t '.$action.' this item.');
        }
    }
}
```

But the API seems to ignore this function. We added this function in our controller. The actions (view, update and delete) are the default `restAction`s.

Our `BaseController` sets actions like this:

```
...
'view' => [
    'class' => 'api\common\components\actions\ViewAction',
    'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
    'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
    'scenario' => $this->viewScenario,
],
...
```

Are we forgetting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We obviously should have seen that the viewAction is not the default but an altered `api\common\components\actions\ViewAction` ... Not sure how we missed that...

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following inside your custom action before executing any other code as it was done in the default view action [(*see source code here*)](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/e9bec0d24653bf5d330f677f53aafd8c4a7feb1a/framework/rest/ViewAction.php#L30-L32):

```
if ($this->checkAccess) {
    call_user_func($this->checkAccess, $this->id, $model);
}
```

*note: `$this->checkAccess` is defined in parent `yii\rest\Action` so your custom ActionView class need to either extend `yii\rest\Action` or redefine the variable `public $checkAccess;`*